# Convert HTML Text to Normal Text adds an extra Carraige Return in Objective-C

Tags: html, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I have a method which would be used to convert the HTML Text to Normal Text.
The issue is that when I pass an HTMl Text, it adds an extra *Carriage Return* to the Normal Text.

Below is the Method and Sample Text which is causing the issue.

Could someone let me know what am I missing or needs to be done for this?
Appreciate the help.

```
- (NSString *)flattenHTML {
    NSString *finalString = self;

    if ([self isEqualToString:kSNREmptyString] == NO) {
        NSAttributedString *attributeString = nil;
        NSData *data = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];

        if (nil != data) {
            NSDictionary *encodingDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@(NSUnicodeStringEncoding)
                                                                     forKey:@"CharacterEncoding"];
            attributeString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:data
                                                    documentAttributes:&encodingDict];
            finalString = [attributeString string];
        }
    }

    return finalString;
}
```

Sample Text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Excepteur
>   sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
>   deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Excepteur
>   sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
>   deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Excepteur
>   sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
>   deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Excepteur
>   sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
>   deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Excepteur
>   sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
>   deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Excepteur
>   sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
>   deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Excepteur
>   sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
>   deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Comment: What's your initial HTML string? I suspect some paragraph `<br>` or something like that that adds `\n`.

Comment: The one that has been specified is the actual HTML String. There is nothing before that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this code help you, Its working fine here.Check it the below code.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
   {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      [self HtmltoText]
   }

-(void)HtmltoText
{
  NSString *Html_Str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head>
                         <title>My First HTML</title></head><body>
                   <p>The HTML head element contains meta data.</p> 
                   <p>Meta data is data about the HTML document. <br/> 
                   Break Next line.</p></body> </html>"];

NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                        initWithData: [Html_Str 
                         dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                        options: @{ 
                           NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: 
                         NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
                                        documentAttributes: nil
                                        error: nil
                                        ];


NSLog(@"Html To Normal %@ ",attributedString );


  }
```